# LazyHorizontalGrid Compose: Arrange cards/tiles horizontally with certian horizontal scroll

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I am a beginner to use Jetpack compose/Andoroid development
I want to create a 8 grid layout with 2 rows and 4 columns
I have used LazyHorizontalGrid compose function, but its default behaviour is to arrange cards/tiles vertically (top/bottom) not side by side. and if i scroll the grid its scrolling to indefinite

`Q1) I want it to arrange side by side with horizontal scroll  (LazyVerticalGrid enables vertical scroll). Is there any way to make it work? or any alternate way to achieve without LazyHorizontalGrid.`

`Q2) After achieving above, how to scroll limit to 1 page or 2 pages, Not infinite scrolling`

```
@Composable
fun OrderGrid() {
   val gridBackgroundColor = Color(10, 150, 200)
   val noOfCardsPerRow = 4
   LazyHorizontalGrid(rows = GridCells.Fixed(2),
       modifier = Modifier.background(gridBackgroundColor),
       contentPadding = PaddingValues(
           start = 4.dp, top = 4.dp, end = 4.dp, bottom = 4.dp
       ),
       content = {
           items(100) {
               Card(
                   colors = CardDefaults.cardColors(
                       containerColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onSurfaceVariant,
                   ),
                   shape = CutCornerShape(1.dp),
                   modifier = Modifier
                       .padding(4.dp)
                       .height(450.dp)
                       .width(470.dp)
               ) {
                   Text(text = "Card "+it, Modifier.background(Color.White))
               }
           }
       })
}
```

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "Not infinite scrolling"? Do you want the items to be shown in batches of 8, i.e. swipe shows items 8 to 15?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your requirements correctly it can be achieved with a `HorizontalPager`. Items could be aligned inside the page in a `Column` with nested `Row`s. Example implementation:

```
val items = (100..200).toList()

@OptIn(ExperimentalFoundationApi::class)
@Composable
fun HorizontalGrid() {
    val rows = 2
    val columns = 4
    val itemsPerPage = rows * columns
    val pages = items.size / itemsPerPage + if (items.size % itemsPerPage == 0) 0 else 1
    val pagerState = rememberPagerState(pageCount = { pages })
    HorizontalPager(state = pagerState) { page ->
        Column(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
            repeat(rows) { row ->
                Row {
                    repeat(columns) { col ->
                        val index = itemsPerPage * page + row * columns + col
                        if (index < items.size) {
                            Card(
                                colors = CardDefaults.cardColors(
                                    containerColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onSurfaceVariant,
                                ),
                                shape = CutCornerShape(1.dp),
                                modifier = Modifier
                                    .padding(4.dp)
                                    .height(450.dp)
                                    .width(470.dp)
                            ) {
                                Text(
                                    text = "Card #$index: ${items[index]}",
                                    modifier = Modifier.background(Color.White),
                                )
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks @Jan Itor, HorizontalPager is working as expected

Comment: [jan ltor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/21636521/jan-itor) is there any way to make it more productive with good performace, Because when there are 10 cards and 2 more cards added, then irrestective of  considering existing 10 cards, HorizontalPager is iterating rows/columns 12 times again instead 2 times ?

Comment: Do you have real performance issues? Pager will recompose the visible page and maybe the next or the previous page too, but so do the Lazy layouts when the underlying data changes. @Krishna